# Trigger Azure Devops pipeline via ADF

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to trigger an azure DevOps pipeline via ADF through web activity?

If not then how to trigger via ADF?

Comment: do you mean the data factory pipeline trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to trigger an Azure Devops release pipeline from ADF.
But you can use a logic app to trigger the same and in turn call the logic app through ADF via web activity.

[image]

Comment: If we can use Logic Apps to solve this, shouldn't there be a REST API equivalent of this? Do you have any idea about simplifying this using REST calls?

Answer (score 1):

As of this time, however, there isn't an existing function that support Azure Data Factory to trigger Azure DevOps pipeline.

But there is a REST API [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) that can queue a pipeline outside the Azure DevOps which may help you.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Here is an example of the request body:

```
{
    "stagesToSkip": [],
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For data factory, you only can add the [pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#trigger-execution):
[image]

When the pipeline runs, the web active will run and call the azure DevOps pipeline. You can use REST API like Jane said. We can not trigger the azure DevOps pipeline directly. There isn't a  active can achieve that.

HTH.